# Oracle get all dates in a month

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to write an SQL statement that would allow me to retrieve all the orders created in the month of September without much luck.

Not working:

```
select order_number, created_date
from orders
where created_date in to_date('2012-09', 'YYYY-MM');
```

Working but too long:

```
select order_number, created_date
from orders
where trunc(created_date) between to_date('2012-09-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') and to_date('2012-09-30', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
select order_number, created_date
from orders
where created_date >= to_date('2012-09-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
and created_date < to_date('2012-10-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

You should try to leave `created_date` untouched to make sure that you can leverage indexes on it nicely.

Comment: Hi rob, how does >= and < differ from using the between clause.

Comment: You are right about leaving created_date untouched to leverage on indexes.

Comment: It means you don't have to truncate the date to make sure you include everything from Sep 30. `BETWEEN` is inclusive at both ends. My query uses `>=` and `<`, to say "anywhere from the start of September, up to BUT NOT INCLUDING the start of October", so a fraction of a second before October is counted.

Answer (score 4):

Use the following code.

```
select order_number, created_date
from orders
where TO_CHAR(created_date, 'YYYY-MM') in '2012-09';
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your version that uses `between` will have better performance, but you can always try the other way around:

```
WHERE TO_CHAR(created_date, 'YYYY-MM') = '2012-09';
```

Another option would be [EXTRACT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm):

```
WHERE 
  EXTRACT(year FROM created_date) = 2012 
  AND EXTRACT(month FROM created_date) = 9;
```

---

**Update:**

[Function-Based Indexes](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/indexes003.htm#i1006674) can be used since **Oracle 8i** to improve the performance of this kind of query:

```
CREATE INDEX ORDS_CRTD_DT_YYYY_MM_IDX 
   ON orders (TO_CHAR(created_date, 'YYYY-MM'));
```

Of course that you should avoid creating indexes for no reason (they will slow down write operations), when there are simpler solutions to your problem - like the one @Rob provided - go with it. Just keep in mind that it is possible to use functions such as `TRUNC`, `TO_CHAR` and `EXTRACT` with a column and still avoid full scans.

Comment: Thanks Anthony for the EXTRACT. Edited your answer from month to year.

Answer (score 0):

*No need to repeat the `created_date` column by using `between`, even the query goes on exploiting the index on that column ,if it has, by using `trunc(to_date('2012-09','yyyy-mm'),'Month')` for the first date and `last_day(to_date('2012-09','yyyy-mm'))` for the last date of the month.*

```
with orders(order_number, created_date) as
(
 select 1, date'2012-08-31' from dual union all
 select 2, date'2012-09-01' from dual union all
 select 3, date'2012-09-02' from dual union all
 select 4, date'2012-09-29' from dual union all   
 select 5, date'2012-09-30' from dual union all   
 select 6, date'2012-10-01' from dual    
),
  param(month) as
(
 select to_date('2012-09','yyyy-mm') from dual    
)    
select order_number, created_date 
  from orders
 cross join param
 where created_date between trunc(month,'Month')
                        and last_day(month);

ORDER_NUMBER    CREATED_DATE
------------    ------------
2               01.09.2012 
3               02.09.2012 
4               29.09.2012 
5               30.09.2012
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/KNTC84472)</kbd>