# Oracle query displays data by month and year

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to display the amount of data by month and year. This is an example of displaying data by date:

```
select count(*) from db.trx where trxdate = to_date('2018-04-23','yyyy-mm-dd')
```

When I try to display the amount of data by month and year, no query results appear. Is there something wrong with the query?

The query:

```
select count(*) from db.trx where trxdate = to_date('2018-04','yyyy-mm')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle get all dates in a month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575922/oracle-get-all-dates-in-a-month)

Comment: Your dates (probably) have a time component and `2018-04-23 12:34:56 = 2018-04-23 00:00:00` is not true so the rows are not matched in your filter condition. It is also probable that your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter is set to just display the date component and not the time component when it display the values as a string so you do not notice that it has a time component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways of accomplishing what you're trying to do. Which one works for you will depend on your database design (for example, the indexes you've created). One way might be this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM olap.trxh2hpdam
 WHERE TRUNC(trxdate, 'MONTH') = DATE'2018-04-01';
```

This will round the date down to the first of the month (and, of course, remove any time portion). Then you simply compare it to the first of the month for which you want the data. However, unless you have an index on `TRUNC(trxdate, 'MONTH')`, this may not be the best course of action; if `trxdate` is indexed, you'll want to use:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM olap.trxh2hpdam
 WHERE trxdate >= DATE'2018-04-01'
   AND trxdate < DATE'2018-05-01';
```

There are a number of functions at your disposal in Oracle (e.g. `ADD_MONTHS()`) in the event that the date you use in your query is supposed to be dynamic rather than static.

Just FYI, there is no reason not to use ANSI date literals when trying to retrieve data by day as well. I'm not sure your original query is a good example of getting data for a particular day, since the Oracle `DATE` datatype does at least potentially include a time:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM olap.trxh2hpdam
 WHERE trxdate >= DATE'2018-04-23'
   AND trxdate < DATE'2018-04-24';
```

or:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM olap.trxh2hpdam
 WHERE TRUNC(trxdate) = DATE'2018-04-23';
```

**EDIT**

In case the month and year are dynamic, I would build a date from them (e.g., `TO_DATE('<year>-<month>-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')`) and then use the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM olap.trxh2hpdam
 WHERE trxdate >= TO_DATE('<year>-<month>-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
   AND trxdate < ADD_MONTHS( TO_DATE('<year>-<month>-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 1 );
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: ya,, i used index(trxdate), i build form with variable month and year to post process to the query...

Comment: how to make the query based on month and year entered? ofcourse month and year are dinamis

Comment: Please see my edit. The mask (in this case `YYYY-MM-DD`) will differ based on how you accept the input. `YYYY` is a 4-digit year and `MM` is a two-digit month (including leading zero if applicable).

Answer (score 3):

You need to apply the function to `trxdate`.  Using your logic:

```
SELECT Count(*) 
FROM   olap.trxh2hpdam 
WHERE  To_char(trxdate, 'YYYY-MM') = '2018-04';
```

However, I strongly recommend that you use direct date comparisons:

```
WHERE trxdate >= date '2018-04-01' 
AND 
trxdate < date '2018-05-01'
```

This will allow the database to use an index on `trxdate`.